# Why is my .NET DynamoDB Query Limit not working?

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb, limit

looking around for about a week now and couldn't find anything so I'm going to post this up.

Working on a project. I'm able to query my dynamoDB index but it seems the limit parameters in my request isn't working. Any help?

```
var request = new QueryRequest
{
    TableName = "exampleTable",
    IndexName = "exampleIndex",
    Limit = 3,
    ExclusiveStartKey = lastKeyEvaluated,
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
        { ":val", new AttributeValue { S = "Yes" } },
        { ":v_1", new AttributeValue { N = "0" }}
    },
    KeyConditionExpression = "Active= :val and Amount > :v_1",
    ProjectionExpression = "Active, Amount",
    ScanIndexForward = false
};
```

I have 6 items on my table. (Prototyping bigger project) One of which has a negative "Amount". So that one is filtered out. However I'm still returned with 5 responses, and not just 3. It seems something is wrong with my limit parameters. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: i think it should be max-items instead of limit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/query.html

Comment: It looks like that's for the CLI. Doesn't seem to transfer over with the SDK. But I appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay cool, so basically the issue was not with the structure of my request but the actual processing of my queryasync.
Whereas I was printing the info before the final key was evaluated now I called my print method after the final key was evaluated.

```
Client.QueryAsync(request, (result) => {

            if (result.Exception == null)
            {
                 //previous spot for the foreach loop and the print method.
                
                lastKeyEvaluated = result.Response.LastEvaluatedKey;
                if (lastKeyEvaluated != null && lastKeyEvaluated.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> item
                    in result.Response.Items)
                    {
                        PrintItem(item);
                    }
                    Query(lastKeyEvaluated);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("last one");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(result.Exception);
            }

        });
```